# Adding components dynamically to a layout

Tags: android-layout, android-view

Good evening I am trying to simply add button into an existing layout...After reading some of others answers I tried this:

```
public void addButton(View v)
{
      Button cb=new Button(this);

      try {
        LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
          //cb.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          l.addView(cb,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.getMessage(),e.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

then I got a null pointer exception as follows:

```
03-01 22:34:03.967: W/System.err(7047): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 22:34:03.967: W/System.err(7047): at custom.component.app.CustomComponentActivity.addButton(CustomComponentActivity.java:49)
03-01 22:34:03.967: W/System.err(7047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 22:34:03.967: W/System.err(7047):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Can anyone tell me what is that?I didn't even use threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by the line:

```
LinearLayout l= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main)
```

`findViewById()` is used to find Views inside a layout. You've used `R.layout.main` by mistake. Change `R.layout.main` to `R.id.<linearlayout>` - replacing `<linearlayout>` with the id you've given the LinearLayout in your XML (the line `android:id="@+id/..."`).

Comment: WOW!!!
Are you kidding me?
It worked simply :')
You don't know how much time I spent on this .
Thank you so much :))))

Comment: I wanted to vote for your answer but I can't (requires 15 reputations)